# Why can't I get 'pik use' working?

Tags: ruby, cmd, pik

I installed Pik and all commands seem to be working fine except for `pik use`.

Here is what happens when I use it at the command-line:

```
C:\Users\Taylor>pik use
Select which Ruby you want:
1. 193: ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]
2. 200: ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
?  1
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

When I try and enter it directly, I get another problem:

```
C:\Users\Taylor>pik use ruby-1.9.3p448
Nothing matches:
```

I have also updated my environment variables to deal with the `%PIK_HOME%` issue.

```
$PIK_HOME% is set to C:\bin
```

But when I enter the following, I don't seem to get the proper output:

```
C:\Users\Taylor>echo %HOME%
%HOME%
```

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: How did you install pik? You should install it from [here](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik)

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution [here](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/issues/118)

Here is what you should do:

1. Find pik installation and edit pik.bat
2. Add SET PIK_HOME=C:\Users\user.pik\ (this should be the path that pik_run.bat is in) to second line (below @ECHO OFF)
3. Save pik.bat and close
4. Open console, run "pik use ruby-bla-bla" (your ruby version)
5. Happily execute ruby -v